# CMAP returning 'TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list''

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've been playing around with Matplotlib recently and I have created a 2D Histogram Heatmap. Now I'm trying to customize it, using a CMAP. Unfortunately, it is not working for me, as it always returns 'TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list''.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix the issue?

```
x = filteredData2019['capacity']
y = filteredData2019['distance']
colors = [(0, 0.33, 0.73), (1, 0.26, 0.26)]
n_bin = [100, 20]
cmap_name = 'my_list'
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap_name, colors = colors, N = n_bin)
newcolors = nump.vstack((testColor(nump.linspace(0, 1, 128)), testColor2(nump.linspace(0, 1, 
128))))
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors, name='OrangeBlue')
fig = plot.hist2d(x, y, bins=(130, 130), cmap = cm, norm = colors.LogNorm(),)
plot.savefig('heatScatterDistance2019.png', dpi = 1000)
```

[image]

Comment: `N` should be an `int`, not a list. `n_bin` is a list. I'm voting `Not reproducible or was caused by a typo`. Review [`matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html) and how the parameters are supposed to be specified.

Answer (score -1):

Your `n_bin = [100, 20]` is a list, which you then pass in as `N`:

`cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(cmap_name, colors=colors, N=n_bin)`

It wants `N` to be something it can turn into an integer. Looking at [this code example](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/custom_cmap.html) which used similar variable names, your `n_bin` should be called `n_bins`, and then you call `from_list` for each one.